# Can I apply a CSS class to another selector in my stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

So say I have a simple document like this:

```html
<head>
    <style>
        .font-regular {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Blah blah...</p>
    <p>Sample text...</p>
    <p>Ignore this...</p>
    <p>The quick brown fox...</p>
</body>
```

I want to apply the `.font-regular` class to every `p` element, without having to type `class="font-regular"` into each element. I also can't just do `p {font-family: sans-serif;}` as I am using the `.font-regular` class to control other elements from one central point.

So, is it possible to give all `p` tags the `.font-regular` class in the stylesheet directly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use both? like this p,.font-regular {font-family: sans-serif; }

Comment: I could, but I would much prefer if there was a way to apply it such as: `p {class: font-regular}` or something like that.

Comment: _So, is it possible to give all p tags the .font-regular class in the stylesheet directly?_ you can't add class to p element with css.

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. You want to apply a class to every `p` element without applying the class to ever `p` element.

Comment: "you can't add class to p element with css. " Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was looking for, a simple answer if it is or isn't possible to do this in the stylesheet.

Comment: From what I understand, you need to use SASS/SCSS or something similar.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I want to apply the class within the CSS (which another user has stated is not possible, thank you) and not apply the contents of the stated class to the element.

Comment: @GameDesert If you are satisfied with the answer you wrote for this question, please accept it. Otherwise you will continue to get answers from people who do not read your question and offer suggestions like `p { font-family: sans-serif; }` and others which you've expressly disallowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sfili_81 stated, it is **not** possible to add CSS classes to an element via the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible via regular CSS; but it is possible with [Less](https://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/).

With Sass, this is possible with the [`@extend` at-rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend):

```
// sass
.font-regular {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p {
  @extend .font-regular;
}
```

This compiles to:

```
// css
.font-regular, p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply `.font-regular` to **every** `p`-tag, you can use JavaScript to add the class `.font-regular` to all `p`-tags, without typing it into every `p`-tag.

Simple define all `p`-tags and create a `for` loop, which adds `.font-regular` to **all** `p`.

```js
let p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (i=0; i < p.length; i++) {
p[i].classList.add('font-regular');
}
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
        .font-regular {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Blah blah...</p>
    <p>Sample text...</p>
    <p>Ignore this...</p>
    <p>The quick brown fox...</p>
</body>
```

I hope this is what you mean.